# LINQ Query for deleting one column from List(Of )

Tags: vb.net, winforms, linq

I have this code:

```
Dim prueba As New SvcEduardo.Service1

Dim listaAnalisis As List(Of SvcService.Analisis)
listaAnalisis = prueba.GetClinicoAnalisis()

'Dim listaModificada = (From l In listaAnalisis
'                       Select l.Colum1, l.Colum2).ToList

DataGridView1.DataSource = listaModificada
```

listaAnalisis is a List which contains classes (Analisis) which have 3 properties each.
listaModificada is suppose to remove one property and keep the other two so i can bind it to a DataGridView.
Can I do this with LINQ? Or is strictly necessary to use another Class structure (AnalisisModified) which only contains the two properties that I need?
I'm trying to avoid that.

**EDIT**

```
'Dim listaModificada = (From l In listaAnalisis
'                       Select l.Colum1, l.Colum2).ToList
```

Here I can't select the columns because listaAnalisis is a List, how can I set the query as it where a single Class(Analisis)?

Comment: why would be my first question. You can set which properties to display in the gridview without having to remove one first. Even then, you can't actually remove the property, just reset the value.

Comment: @BrokenGlass i didn't because i don't know how to set the linq query to work with the list! can't get the colums from it!

Comment: @Chris how can i set the properties i want to show from codebehind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't need to remove the property from the class. Simply don't show the column/property on your GridView.

Perhaps you can toggle the `AutoGenerateColumns` property:

```
DataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = False
```

Then explicity set the columns on the DGV that you actually want to be shown. You can do this at design-time, or at run-time:

```
dataGridView1.Columns.Add( "CustomerName", "Name")
dataGridView1.Columns.Add( "CustomerStatus", "Current Status")
dataGridView1.Columns.Add( "CustContactPhone", "Phone")
```

or more granular control on the column:

```
Dim dvc as New DataGridViewColumn()
dvc.HeaderText = "ID"
dvc.DataPropertyName = "CustomerID"
' all the properties you need.
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(dvc)
dataGridView1.DataSource = listaModificada
```

Comment: thank you @p.campbell i used your aproach of AutoGenerateColumns = False!

Answer (score 2):

You still want to AutoGenerateColumns, so dont set that to false as it will stop the generation of all columns after that.

Instead under the AutoGenerateColumns Event for your datagrid try using a Select statement on the column header, and using e.Cancel for the one you don't want to show.

Ex.

```
  Private Sub SearchResults_AutoGeneratingColumn(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Controls.DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs) Handles SearchResults.AutoGeneratingColumn

Dim colName As String
colName = e.Column.Header
Select Case colName
  Case "_city"
    e.Column.Header = "City"
  Case "_firstName"
    e.Column.Header = "First Name"
  Case "_lastName"
    e.Column.Header = "Last Name"
  Case "_state"
    e.Column.Header = "State"
  Case "_orgCode", "_accntCode", "_state_name"
    e.Cancel = True
End Select
```

End Sub

The final case handles the ones that you dont want to show.
In this example, i have also changed the names of the column headers to a more readable name. Hope this helps!

Comment: nice idea! i certainly going to use it in the future! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A very simple example

```
 <asp:DataGrid ID="Grid" runat="server"AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="Property1" DataField="Property1"></asp:BoundColumn>
            <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="Property2" DataField="Property2"></asp:BoundColumn>
    </asp:DataGrid>
```

Comment: thank you Chris but i'm working in WinForms, i'm used to asp.net but in Winforms i'm a little behind.